# using alfresco as an smtp mail server

Tags: email, smtp, alfresco

I want to use Alfresco as a normal e-mail server. Alfresco is able to receive mails for a e-mail-address if its user belongs to the EMAIL_CONTRIBUTORS group.

But I want Alfresco to receive e-mails independent from which e-mail-address the mail was send?
Is there any way to disable the check if the sender belongs to the EMAIL_CONTRIBUTORS group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be below can help

**Inbound email service**

The inbound email service deals with incomming email messages.

email.inbound.enabled=true

Enable/Disable the inbound email service. The service could be used by processes other than
the Email Server (e.g. direct RMI access) so this flag is independent of the Email Service.

**email.inbound.unknownUser=anonymous**

The username to authenticate with when the sender address is not recognised in alfresco.

There are some other things as well which will use full for setting allowed sender.

**Allowed senders**

A comma separated list of email REGEX patterns of allowed senders. If there are any values in the list then all sender email addresses must match. For example:
  .*\@alfresco.com, .*\@alfresco.org
email.server.allowed.senders
list of patterns to allow.

**Blocked Senders**

A comma separated list of email REGEX patterns of blocked senders. The list of blocked senders has priority over the allowed senders.
If the sender email address matches this then the message will be rejected. For example:
  .*\@hotmail.com, .*\@googlemail.com
email.server.blocked.senders
list of patterns to block.

You can look in to more details in below link.

https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Inbound_SMTP_Email_Server_Configuration

If this not helps may be you will need to look deeply in to alfresco mail services.

Answer (score 2):

I also asked this question in the [Alfresco forums](http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/configuration/using-alfresco-smtp-mail-server) an got there the hint, that I need to set the email.inbound.unknownUser value in the alfresco-global properties file.

So follow first [this](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/community-videos-12.html) tutorial and set the email.inbound.unknownUser to test (the test user from the tutorial). Than the alfresco should receive emails from any sender. I hope that will help someone with a similar problem.